# Will I get better performance with Brisk ZC plugs?

Tags: sparkplugs

I was looking into Brisk ZC Multispark plugs. The design is interesting. it doesn't have a ground strap like regular plugs, nor is it one with multiple ground straps to get in the way of the flame front.

I'm thinking of putting them into my 1990 Pontiac Lemans (1.6L engine). Will I see better gas mileage or performace?

Comment: While they do look interesting, I doubt you are going to see any real improvement in power or gas mileage, mainly because: 1) the engine in question is only a 1.6l normally aspirated engine, and 2) IT GETS GREAT GAS MILEAGE TO BEGIN WITH. I used to own an 88 LeMans (I think was the year) 5-speed. Would pull down over 30mpg on the highway at 80mph cruising speed. Great little car. Bought it new off the lot.

Comment: Old news, these no-ground plugs - in the 60s & 70s there was a brand called "Fire Ring" with pretty much the same claims. They were no big woo.

Answer (score 1):

No. If they were that great, they would come standard in your car. Vehicle manufacturers are under tremendous pressure to improve fuel economy, so every relatively cheap modification or part they can use will definitely be used. If they didn't use something, it's either because they're too expensive or they don't really perform as well as stated.

Answer (score 0):

When your engine was in its design and testing phase, OEM manufacturers of the various components will have tested and tested again all of the component parts to an exacting standard. You will not gain any advantage by detracting off of this standard. The Brisk plugs may offer some enhancements in a race tuned engine, but the suggestion that a plug without a protruding ground electrode will accelerate the flame front to any appreciable amount would not really stand upto critical examination.

Comment: Have you ever heard of indexing and shrouding?