# Replace shaft seal in power steering pump

Tags: power-steering, seal

I want to replace the shaft seal (4th element on the schematic) in my power steering pump.

My question is: How do I remove triangular element of power steering pump?

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Knowing exactly what this belongs to would help you in getting it done. I'd at least be able to find the procedure or come up with one of my own. Please include year/make/model of the vehicle. It also helps others find the same information if they need it.

Comment: From another question (here -http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11590/will-i-get-better-performance-with-brisk-zc-plugs - It could be a 1990 Pontiac Lemans